# Error while assembling the code in x86 Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, as86

I have the following code:

```
.global _launchProgram
_launchProgram:
push bp
mov bp, sp
push cs
mov bx, [bp + 4]
mov cs, bx
mov es, bx
eseg
call #0x0
pop bx
mov cs, bx
pop bp
ret
```

In this code I am trying to make it to jump to another piece of code and execute it. This code is being called from C as shown below:

```
launchProgram(segment) //Here segment is an integer which holds the 
                       //memory segment where I have loaded my code
```

Thus in this function I make cs register to be equal to the segment variable and I use `call 0x0` to jump to the start of that segment. But when I run it using:

```
as86 launchProgram.asm -o launchProgram.o
```

I get the following error:

```
00010 000C           E8         0000            call #0x0
***** relocation impossible.................................^
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your `call #0x0` seems to specify an IP (Instruction Pointer)-relative call in as86 (an offset relative to the next instruction). Was that intentional? as86 might be complaining because it expected a label or a symbol instead, which the linker would be able to resolve (relocate) if needed.

The as86 man page has the following:

> The 'near  and  'far'  do  not  allow  multi-segment  programming,  all 'far'
>   operations are specified explicitly through the use of the instructions: jmpi,
>   jmpf, callf, retf, etc. The 'Near' operator can be used to force  the  use  of
>   80386 16bit conditional branches. The 'Dword' and 'word' operators can control
>   the size of operands on far jumps and calls.

The code assembles if I use `callf 0x12345678,0x1234` instead, which generates the following instructions:

```
$ as86 a.asm -o a.o
$ objdump -D -b binary -mi386 -Maddr16,data16,intel a.o
...
3b: 8e cb                   mov    cs,bx
3d: 8e c3                   mov    es,bx
3f: 26 66 9a 78 56 34 12    es call 0x1234:0x12345678
46: 34 12 
48: 5b                      pop    bx
48: 5b                      pop    %bx
...
```

(`-b binary` it needed since it's raw code, `-mi386` selects the instruction set, and `-Maddr16,data16,intel` selects Intel syntax and 16-bit code, which seems to be what as86 generates by default.)

The second operand to `callf` seems to be the segment selector part of the address (having a single operand to `callf` causes as86 to complain). My x86-fu is too weak to say if the segment override on the call actually makes sense there. You'd want `callf #0x0,#0x0` in your code, of course.

If you want to "trick" as86 into generating a relative `call` that's identical to what you're trying to do (not sure if this makes sense -- you might get random bits from whatever IP happens to be), then you could do the following:

```
eseg
call zero_offset
zero_offset: pop bx
```

The output is

```
  53:   26 e8 00 00             es call 0x57
```

, where the `00 00` part shows that the offset is 0.

Comment: Thanks...but I still do not understand how would I jump to the start of the (new) cs segment. I want to jump to cs:0x0 but the as86 is still complaining if I use `callf cs, 0x0`but this `callf cs` seems to be working. In general, how can I make far calls using registers??

Comment: @sarthak: `callf cs` seems to generate an FF instruction (see rows 3 and 4 in http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html), which `objdump` just displays as "(bad)", so using `CS` with those probably isn't legal. I'm not an x86 expert, but try simply doing `callf 0x0,0x0` after `eseg`. Perhaps the segment override prefix will override the 0x0 segment selector in the instruction.

Comment: Do you really need to calculate the segment address at runtime btw? Otherwise you could probably just put it directly into the `callf` (as the second operand).

Comment: In what environment are you going to run this code by the way?

Comment: No I just need to jump to the start of the segment and I am using qemu for running

Comment: Are you executing in real mode?

Comment: If you know the address of the segment, you should be able to do `callf <segment>,0x0`, where the called address will be `16*<segment> + 0`. This will automatically set `CS` too, and push it to the stack. The call should be matched by a `retf`, which will restore `CS` from the stack as well.

Comment: If you don't know the address at compile-time, it seems you can use `callf` and a memory operand (address where the address to call is stored) for the address as well (using whatever syntax as86 has for variables). That will also set `CS`.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `callf 0x0,<segment>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think setting cs before call is a good idea, the called procedure don't know how to return. You have to execute a far call,
call segment:offset. This will push the value of the ip and cs register on stack for return. For your code something like: call cs:0x00
Also is esag a x86 instruction?

Se  [this](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html) link

Comment: I think you are talking about the nasm syntax. With as86 you cannot use the syntax like `call cs:0x0` instead you have to split this over two commands like I have done so eseg followed by call 0x0 should be `call es:0x0`